# Deselect UIView "button" when dragging finger off of it

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a `UIView` that I added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to so that I can handle clicks and have that `UIView` work like a button.

```
let longPressGtr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(longPressSelector))
longPressGtr.minimumPressDuration = 0.1
myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
myView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGtr)


@objc func longPressSelector(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue // my button is blue
        doSomething()
    }
}

func doSomething() {
    print("view was pressed")
}
```

This works, but the one thing that doesn't is when I press and hold on my UIView but drag my finger off the view, the "button" doesn't unselect. It still fires `doSomething()`. A regular `UIButton` will deselect the button and not fire it's onClick if you are holding down on it an drag your finger off the view.

How can I implement this functionality into my `UIView`?

Or is there a better way to make a `UIView` act like a button?

Comment: what do you mean by **It still fires the function like a click**. does is mean that `doSomething` is still fired ? but the button color does not turned into blue ?

Comment: @RatulSharker Yes. it means doSomething is fired

Comment: but your button doesn't turned blue, right ? is it the problem ?

Comment: @RatulSharker the button turns blue and doSomething is fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the gesture is inside the view.

```
@objc func longPresserDidFire(_ presser: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let gestureIsInside = myView.point(inside: presser.location(in: myView), with: nil)
    switch presser.state {
    case .began, .changed:
        if gestureIsInside {
            myView.backgroundColor = .blue
        } else {
            myView.backgroundColor = .gray
        }
    case .cancelled:
        myView.backgroundColor = .gray
    case .ended:
        myView.backgroundColor = .gray
        if gestureIsInside {
            doSomething()
        }
    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great. Could this be an extension?

Answer (score 0):

When you drag your finger outside of the view, `gestureRecognizer` is probably translated to `failed` or `cancelled` state, so you need to add handling of this cases `gestureRecognizer.state == .failed` and `gestureRecognizer.state == .cancelled`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding condition of gestureRecognizer state changed that's why it is accepting the end state.

```
@objc func longPressSelector(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {

    } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {

    }else if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {

    }
}
```

Add one more condition and check if it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
@objc func longPressSelector(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

}
```

Place **UILongPressGestureRecognizer** instead of  **UITapGestureRecognizer** and check it

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: It matters, but it doesn't solve the problem. Good catch Nirav.